# How to get Number of days between 2 dates when specific condition is met?

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I want to get the number of days between two dates based on specific condition, here is the image illustration of what I am talking about:

[image: Image Illustration]

I need to devise a formula to calculate number of days from dates (column C) it takes `ID = 1` to reach from `L1` to `L2` , so ideally the output for `ID = 1` should be:

> L1 : 0
>
> L2 : 2022-07-14 - 2022-07-06 = 8

Same for other ids (2,3). I am just a beginner trying to learn, so I apologize for my ordinary question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAYS` will give you the day count between dates. try:

```
=DAYS(SINGLE(FILTER(C:C; B:B="L2"; A:A=1)); 
      SINGLE(FILTER(C:C; B:B="L1"; A:A=1)))
```

---

```
=DAYS(SINGLE(FILTER(C:C; B:B="L2"; A:A=2)); 
      SINGLE(FILTER(C:C; B:B="L1"; A:A=2)))
```

---

```
=DAYS(SINGLE(FILTER(C:C; B:B="L2"; A:A=3)); 
      SINGLE(FILTER(C:C; B:B="L1"; A:A=3)))
```

Comment: thank you, it works for ID=1, can we use this formula for ID = 2 and 3 also?